# Function from R2 to R

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Hi guys  I have $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined for $f(x,y)=\dfrac{xy}{1+x^2+y^2}$, so i need

a) Study Injectivity and Surjectivity

b) Find $Img(f)$

c) Find $f^{-1}([0,1])$

I just prove that f is not Injective but its Surjective ... Can someone help me?

Comment: If $f$ is surjective, then by definition it's image is what?

Comment: Injective: consider that $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$. Surjective: for example $f(x,y) \le \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I used $x_1=(1,-1)$ and $x_2=(-1,1)$ to prove is Not Injective